# (somebody) demonstrated improved results

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering if the following sentence is correct:

In his PhD defense, he demonstrated (his) improved results.

Also, should we use the determiner "his" here? What I am trying to convey is that he did a demo about his research and showed the results that had been achieved.

Thanks,

L

Comment: Did he obtain the same results (his findings were similar to someone else's, etc.) or actually get improved results? I think  you might need to rephrase your sentence.

Comment: Actually, he got improved results.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with either sentence. However, the inclusion of *his* identifies whose the results are that he presented.

> He presented improved results — *could be anyone’s (including his)*
>   He presented his improved results — *the results are results only he obtained*

What is not clear is what his results are an improvement upon. A previous set of his own results? Or results someone else had obtained? This information could be provided by context, or you may need to make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sentence with the closest meaning per my understanding:

> During his PhD defense, he presented the improved results (of/for some theory/phenomenon/process/etc) obtained in his dissertation.

If you want to keep your version, I still suggest changing **in** to **during** and not having **his**, because it's not **his results** that he shows, it is **the results of his work**.

Comment: Hi Arsen, thanks for your answer. It makes perfect sense not to use "his" here and "presented" is the exact word I was looking for. However, I'm not sure about changing "in his PhD defense" to "during his PhD defense". Could you shed more light on that, thanks!